# Crash when using university wifi

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro, crash

I recently bought a MacBook Air 13", to use at my university (Technical University of Denmark).

But when I am using my laptop in a place with many other laptops, OSX crashes every 5 minutes (kernel panic). Other people have experienced the problem here: [Apple Support Thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3218344?start=0&tstart=0)

Someone in the thread suggests disabling IPv6, but this does not solve the problem.

Have anybody in here experienced this problem, or can anybody figure out a solution?

I use: OSX Version 10.7.2, Build 11C74

Comment: What OS X version?

Comment: When you say OS X is crashing, what exactly is it doing? Is it a kernel panic, system hang, application crash, random shutdown, etc?

Comment: OSX Version 10.7.2, Build 11C74. It is a kernel panic, as described in the link i supplied.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the linked Apple support thread, I believe the problem is likely Apple's fault. My advice is:

- Take the MBA to an Apple Store (with a genius bar appointment) or call Apple support to report the problem
- Make sure you have installed all software updates (perhaps you have, but this is not mentioned)

Comment: I guess I will have to try that. But it seems somebody (lindsayfromleander) from the support thread already got a hold of Apple, with no result.